# Remove URL params on routing

Tags: routes, sapui5

I am calling a view passing url parameters to perform specific custom actions. Once, these actions have been processed, I would like to use the router to move to another page but removing the url parameters first.

To be more specific:

Link containing url parameters leads to main page as its route has an empty pattern.

```
example.com/?urlParam1=Test&urlParam2=Boum
```

Once the controller has processed the request, I am using the router to nav to another view by calling

```
getRouter().navTo("ViewX", {}, false)
```

The url in the browser changes to

```
example.com/?urlParam1=Test&urlParam2=Boum/#/ViewX
```

The url parameters are still visible. Any chance to remove them?

Cheers

Comment: Please be a little more specific. Could you provide some example code?

Comment: I am not sure of the authors intention but I have a similar problem. If calling an app with startup parameters (http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/07/9561b716bb4f2f8ae4e47bacbdb86d/content.htm) I will build a navigation. But the parameter will still be in the URL. So the question I have: How to remove the "startupparameter" from the routing url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question you have lets say 2 routes and something like this

```
routes : [ {
                pattern : "Val1",
                name : "Main",
                view : "Main",
                viewId : "Start"

            },{
                pattern : "Val2",
                name : "Next",
                view : "Next",
                viewId : "Start1"

            } ]
```

Now you invoke the route **"Main"** and your URL will be something like 
**http://applicationurl:port/ProjectName#Val1**

and from here you invoke route Next then system will automatically change the url to 
**http://applicationurl:port/ProjectName#Val2**

This is supported out of the box by SAPUI5 routing . Is there something different you want to achieve?

**EDIT : Updated Answer**

Nope not from the current view. 
But i can suggest a workaround. Have one more route to the same view without the parameters of your concern. Now you can call the route after the action is performed leading to same view being loaded. 
Couple of points to remember

1. Be careful with the routes , they should not conflict.
2. The same view is loaded again leading to routeMatched events being called and needs to handled carefully.

As a side note the routes are meant for Bookmarking and addressable feature. I would suggest you think about handling the action via the EventBus in SAPUI5.