# Fiori -- Cross application navigation; Handling startup parameters?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

This question is related to:

- [Fiori - Cross Application Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844715/fiori-cross-application-navigation)
- http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/07/9561b716bb4f2f8ae4e47bacbdb86d/content.htm
- [Remove URL params on routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922199/remove-url-params-on-routing)

My use case is like this:

I have multiple applications that should link to others (deep).
Since documentation of cross navigation mention to avoid deep links I decided to use a startup parameter.

For example:

Application A has a list of some items in the detail view of one item there is a reference to another application B that contains some other details.
Assume A shows article details and B shows some details of a producer of an article.

Application A would now use some navigation like this:

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").hrefForExternal({
  target : { semanticObject : "ApplicationB", action : "display" },
  params : { "someID" : "102343333"}
})
```

Now in application B I use code like this inside the Component.js at the end of the init method.

```
var oRouter = that.getRouter().initialize();
var oComponentData = this.getComponentData();
if (oComponentData.startupParameters) {
    oRouter.navTo("SomeView", {
        someId : oComponentData.startupParameters.someID[0],
    }, false);
}
```

First question: Is this the right place for handling the startup parameters?

Second question: If I using the navigation the startup parameter will still be in the code, I would prefer to remove it, but how?

### Update

In the target application (B) it would lead to the following URL:

```
https://server/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=100&sap-language=EN#SemObject-display?someID=102343333&/SomeView(102343333)/
```

Anyhow I would prefere to have something like this:

```
https://server/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=100&sap-language=EN#SemObject-display?/SomeView(102343333)/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter must be retrieved as

```
var oComponentData = this.getComponentData();
if (oComponentData.startupParameters) {
    oRouter.navTo("SomeView", {
        someId : oComponentData.startupParameters.someID[0],
    }, false);
```

as you write. In Fiori applications, the startup parameters injected into the Component data of your constructor may have been renamed, enriched by further default values etc.. Thus they may be distinct from the parameter one observes in the url. Applications are advised to refrain from trying to inspect the URL directly.

If one supplies a very long set of url parameters, one will observer that the FLP replaces some of them with sap-intent-param=AS123424 ("compacted URL") to work around url length restrictions on some platforms and in bookmarks, in the 
getComponentData().startupParameters one will receive the full set of parameters).

As to the second question. 
No, there is currently no way to "cleanse" the URL and avoid the redundancy between and inner app route.

SemObject-display?someID=102343333&/SomeView(102343333)/ 
which after navigation may look like 
SemObject-display?someID=102343333&/SomeView(102343999)/

App was started with 102343333, but then user navigated within the app to another item (102343999).

Any change in the "Shell-part" of the has (SemObject-display?someID102343333) will lead to a cross-app-navigation (reinstantiation of your component) with a different startupParameter.

(There are cases where this is desired in the flow, e.g. a cross navigation from a OrgUnit factsheet  to the parent OrgUnit factsheet via a link).

There were ideas within SAP to fuse the inner-app routes and the intent parameters,  but they were not carried out, as it's mostly url aesthetics.

Note: To support boomarking, one has to respect both startup parameters and 
inner app route during component instantiation, 
assuming the user created a bookmark on

SemObject-display?someID=102343333&/SomeView(102343999)/ 
(While he was looking at 9999(!)).

When reinstantiating the app, the inner app route should take higher precedence than startup-parameters.

So amend the code to:

```
var oComponentData = this.getComponentData();
if (oComponentData.startupParameters) {
    if (sap.ui.core.getHashChanger().getHash()=== "") {
         // if no inner app route present, navigate 
         oRouter.navTo("SomeView", {
               someId : oComponentData.startupParameters.someID[0],
         }, false);
    }
```

}

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ushell.services.CrossApplicationNavigation.html

SAP Fiori Launchpad for Developers, Navigation Concept
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/907ae317-cb47-3210-9bba-e1b5e70e5c79?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&59575491523067

Comment: sap.ui.core.getHashChanger().getHash() seems not to exist. Potentially you mean var oHashChanger = new sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger(); var sHash = oHashChanger.getHash(); ? Anyhow the hash would also include the semantic object name and therefore it won't be empty in any case. Is there a nice way to check if the routing part of the app is empty?

Comment: I encountered same thing in UI5 1.44 but sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger.getInstance() will give you an instance of the hash changer, it doesn't contain the semantic object name and action, just the url hash after this so on your initial route it does return a empty string like the suggested code above

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues navigating from a Fiori elements app in to a deep page in a freestyle UI5 app and then answer from @user6649841 provided most the solution for my requirement.

In my instance, navigating from the elements list report (app "A") in to the target freestyle app (app "B") I didn't want the worklist/initial page in app B to display at all and instead go straight to the detail page without a flickering of the initial app screen.

The below worked for me, note though it doesn't solve the ugly URL issues. In my case I'm not fussed about it as my nav back will nav back to the elements list report (App A) and never show the worklist page in App B so the user will never make another search on top of this URL which would lead with inconsistent inner and outer keys

Component.js (at end of init function after all the standard sap code, but before router initialization):

```
var oComponentData = this.getComponentData();
var startupParams = oComponentData.startupParameters;

 if (startupParams && startupParams.myQueryStringParamName && startupParams.myQueryStringParamName[0]) {
    //In my case using hash changer as I dont want the original landing page (default route) to be
    //in the history, so the detail page loads straight away and nav back will cause to nav back to App A
    var hashChanger = sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger.getInstance();
    hashChanger.replaceHash("detailPage/" + startupParams.myQueryStringParamName[0]);
}
//initialise after the above so the new hash is set and it doesnt initially load the
//page assigned to the default route causing a flickering and nav slide effect
this.getRouter().initialize();
```

Looking at the UI5 SDK in UI5 1.48 and above in the initialize method of router you can pass in a boolean to tell it to ignore the initial hash so possibly can do a simpler implementation in newer releases of UI5

Answer (score 0):

**Is Component.js right place for handling the startup parameters?**

Depends,if you have multiple views and you want to dynamically route based on the incoming parameters. Else you can handle in specific view also.

*Your second question was not quite clear to me.*

Nevertheless, if you want to only specific cases of startup parameters, then from Source App, set some flag to understand where is the request coming from and handle accordingly. So this way, your normal navigation won't be tampered.

Comment: Assume two standalone apps having a possibility to search. For example article app and producer app. Now an article has a producer and it should be possible to jump to the producer detail view in the producer app from the article app -- so without seeing the search screen of the producer.

Comment: that's doable.. you have context parameter which you can pass

Comment: If you have a look into my code that's what I do. But the startup parameters look like this BASE?param1=value&param2=value my normal # Navigation would do something like this /DetailPage(ID) if I combine this I would have BASE?param1=value&param2=value&/DetailPage(ID) that's not so nice.