# How to change FLP - Parameter within the same app

Tags: sapui5

I have an app with two tiles on the Fiori Launchpad, setting a URL parameter to differ. I result in having following two Hashes :

```
#SemanticObject-action?myparam=tile1&/inner/app/path
#SemanticObject-action?myparam=tile2&/inner/app/path
```

Now I want to navigate from one tile to the other.

In the Component.js I get that parameter:

```
this.getComponentData().startupParameters.myparam[0];
```

and so I can decide how it has to act.

Now how to change that param at a controller? I tried (what did not work):

```
//simply overwriting does not work
this.getComponentData().startupParameters.myparam[0] = "tile2";

sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").toExternal(
{params : {myparam: "tile2"}});
```

What I do not want is using things like `window.location`, regex for replacement of "tile1" with "tile2" or such inproper solutions.

> `window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(sOldParam, sNewParam);`

Comment: Have you reviewed this: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ushell.services.CrossApplicationNavigation.html ?

Comment: @Matti.b I am in the same Application. So why CrossApplicatino ? I do not want a hardcoded Semantic Object, since that could change. It should just take the same.

Comment: Are you using routing within your app to differentiate the two? Because then you can just use the router.
Also check out this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128601/fiori-cross-application-navigation-handling-startup-parameters